# Hiding MacOS Toolbar when in fullscreen

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I was wondering if it is possible to hide the toolbar when in full screen using CSS. I've tried searching StackOverflow for some answer but sadly with no success.

Basically, go from this:
[image]
Too this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot affect the host application interface using `CSS`. There is a `Javascript` solution, however.

`document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();` Be aware that you should also track keyboard actions like ESC, and provide a button for users to exit this experience as well.

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) from Mozilla. Also according to the [Can I Use database](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen), Desktop Safari has only partial support and iOS Safari has NO support so how well this works will vary based on the browser.

I should point out that this isn't really the same as Kiosk mode. Kiosk mode can be used to block access from other applications/websites. This DOES NOT do that.